# How to select rows with all alphabets and numbers in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains 100000 rows and in that there is a column say drugname whose type is varchar.

The values of the column may start with 0 to 9 and 
A-Z or a-z.

I need a query that returns 25000 rows. And out of that 25000 rows it should contain all the alphabets and numbers.

Say for example,

- alphabet A contains 500 rows
- alphabet B contains 500 rows
- number 1 contains 400 rows
- number 2 contains 300 rows etc...

that includes all the numbers and alphabets and overall it should have 25000 rows.

Comment: you mean something like: `select substring(drugname,1,1) as initial,count(*) from tableName group by substring(drugname,1,1)`    ??  or `select substring(drugname,1,1) as initial,count(*) from (select * from tableName limit 25000) A group by substring(drugname,1,1)`

Comment: Should the return  row counts for each letter / number  be in the same ratio as in the database? i.e. if 10% of the rows contain 'Z' then should that be 10% of the 25000 rows?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us some code... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you want....

Comment: @RyanVincent The return rows need not be in same ratio.But is should contain all the alphabets and numbers.For example only i told 500 rows,400 rows etc..

Comment: @Pevara I have tried using regular expressions but that is not exactly i want or correct.

Comment: @ZahiroMor I dont want the count of each alphabets and characters. I want the entire row from the table.In that, it should contain all the alphabets and numbers

Comment: Perhaps you mean letters, not alphabets, and digits, not numbers?

Comment: @jarlh Yes. The starting may be a letter or a number.But the query should return 25000 rows with all the letters and numbers as starting one.

Comment: sorry. I do not understand. maybe show us an example output?

Answer (score 0):

First select minimal set of ids for all the groups (by the first char)

```
select min(id) as substrId
from the_table
group by substr(value,0,1)
```

Then use the subselect to return the selected ids first (to represent all the groups) and then some random ids

```
select t1.* 
from the_table t1
    left join (select min(id) as substrId
               from the_table
               group by substr(value,0,1)) sub on t1.id=sub.substrId
order by ifnull(sub.substrId, 0) desc
limit 25000
```

Thus all the distinct group members are included in the final result set.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate the rows based on the first character.  Then use the enumeration to get the rows:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             (@rn := if(@l = left(d.drugname, 1), @rn + 1,
                        if(@l := left(d.drugname, 1), 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from drugs d cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @l := '') params
      order by d.drugname
     ) d
order by seqnum
limit 25000;
```

Note:  This returns the rows with the smallest drug names for each letter.  If you want random ones, then use this `order by`:

```
order by left(d.drugname, 1), rand()
```